# Pasting a range of values from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

So everything was actually pasting correctly to the workbook, however, I added an extra column of data that has a formula entered in it. Now when I run the macro it is copying and pasting the formula rather than the value generated from the formula.

I went in and changed `wbData.ActiveSheet.Paste` to `wbData.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial x1PasteValue` but it is not working. Wondering if I inserted it into the wrong location?

```
 Dim wbTime As Workbook
   Set wbTime = ThisWorkbook
   Dim wbData As Workbook
   Dim LastRow As Long

   Set wbTime = ActiveWorkbook
   With wbTime.Sheets("Production Time Sheet")
       LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   End With
   wbTime.Sheets("Production Time Sheet").Range("A6:O" & LastRow).Copy

   Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("S:\Lean Carrollton Initiative\Michael\Time Sheet Data - LT Test.xlsx")

   wbData.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial x1PasteValue Destination:=Worksheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

   wbData.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: After `PasteSpecial` it should be `xlPasteValues`.  That is the letter L after the x, not the number 1.

Comment: And another error that could be easily prevented with `Option explicit`.

Comment: It is a number 1. The lowercase L and 1 look in the same.

Comment: It should be "L"

Comment: yeah, but it must be an lowercase L

Comment: The only error I have is when I add the `PasteSpecial x1PasteValues` if I keep just `Paste` it works fine. However, I need to copy the value in one column range instead of the formula.

Comment: I have tried it, no go. It says 'Compile Error:   Expected: end of statement' and highlights where is reads `Destination:=`.

Comment: the parameter to copy values is **`xlPasteValues`**, not **`x1PasteValues`**. `x1PasteValues` is undefined, Excel will translate this to 0 unless you force it to correct such errors by using `Option explicit`.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `xlPasteValues` to separate the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always select the range to paste too first

```
Worksheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValue
```

Comment: still using this invalid `x1PasteValue`.

Comment: @Max Russell thank you, this worked after rearranging it.

Comment: @FunThomas - I edited to `xlPasteValue` (a lowercase "L" instead of a `1`)